# Raw data to Array or Json using js

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, node.js

It would be helpful if someone could assist on this. I want to store this raw data into array from `BEGIN:VEVENT` to `END:VEVENT`

## raw data

```
BEGIN : VEVENT\r\nDTSTART;
TZID = America / New_York : 20161231 T123000\r\nDTEND;
TZID = America / New_York : 20161231 T133000\r\nRRULE : FREQ = WEEKLY;
UNTIL = 20170211 T045959Z;
BYDAY = SA\r\nDTSTAMP : 20170228 T012109Z\r\nUID : h742jrf72h1r4oferera9dp070@google.com\r\nCREATED : 20170102 T190437Z\r\nDESCRIPTION : \r\nLAST - MODIFIED : 20170211 T152911Z\r\nLOCATION : \r\nSEQUENCE : 0 \r\nSTATUS : CONFIRMED\r\nSUMMARY : happy\r\nTRANSP : OPAQUE\r\nEND : VEVENT\r\nBEGIN : VEVENT\r\nDTSTART;
TZID = America / New_York : 20170106 T170000\r\nDTEND;
TZID = America / New_York : 20170106 T173000\r\nRRULE : FREQ = WEEKLY;
BYDAY = FR\r\nDTSTAMP : 20170228 T012109Z\r\nUID : ukad1og7htm89pc8j4di4otlk8_R20170106T220000@google.com\r\nCREATED : 20141126 T041733Z\r\nDESCRIPTION : \r\nLAST - MODIFIED : 20170120 T210013Z\r\nLOCATION : sds\r\nSEQUENCE : 0 \r\nSTATUS : CONFIRMED\r\nSUMMARY : Gold / Blue / Green Weapons\r\nTRANSP : OPAQUE\r\nBEGIN : VALARM\r\nACTION : NONE\r\nTRIGGER;
VALUE = DATE - TIME : 19760401 T005545Z\r\nEND : VALARM\r\nEND : VEVENT\r\nBEGIN : VEVENT\r\nDTSTART;
TZID = America / New_York : 20161229 T160000\r\nDTEND;
TZID = America / New_York : 20161229 T164500\r\nDTSTAMP : 20170228 T012109Z\r\nUID : 8 thf9943qdnjkcrtlvt6k8kjmg@google.com\r\nRECURRENCE - ID;
TZID = America / New_York : 20161229 T160000\r\nCREATED : 20160612 T220329Z\r\nDESCRIPTION : \r\nLAST - MODIFIED : 20170117 T200013Z\r\nLOCATION : \r\nSEQUENCE : 0 \r\nSTATUS : CONFIRMED\r\nSUMMARY : Juniors school\r\nTRANSP : OPAQUE\r\nBEGIN : VALARM\r\nACTION : NONE\r\nTRIGGER;
VALUE = DATE - TIME : 19760401 T005545Z\r\nEND : VALARM\r\nEND : VEVENT\r\n
```

## expected output

```
[
  {
    Hide Copy Code BEGIN: VEVENT,
    DTSTART: 20160314 T093000Z,
    DTEND: 20160314 T143000Z,
    DTSTAMP: 20160427 T141329Z,
    CREATED: 20160228 T142659Z,
    DESCRIPTION: For assembler,
    LAST - MODIFIED: 20160314 T133208Z,
    SEQUENCE: 0,
    STATUS: CONFIRMED,
    END: VEVENT
  }, {
    Hide Copy Code BEGIN: VEVENT,
    DTSTART: 20160314 T093000Z,
    DTEND: 20160314 T143000Z,
    DTSTAMP: 20160427 T141329Z,
    CREATED: 20160228 T142659Z,
    DESCRIPTION: For assembler,
    LAST - MODIFIED: 20160314 T133208Z,
    SEQUENCE: 0,
    STATUS: CONFIRMED,
    END: VEVENT
  }
]
```

I see it works in ruby. I tried some api for js converting icasdata to Json, but it doesn't fetch exact data so I'm thinking if I can read the raw data and pass it to an array without any API. Any suggestion on above question that will help. Thanks.

Comment: are you sure the json output you are expecting is a valid JSON...

Comment: the raw data is in a txt file?

Comment: ya i got the raw data from icalendar file...either its Json or array in above mentioned format... I am not sure how i can convert the raw data into array in java script as i am the beginner....any suggestion would be helpful!!  ps: All i am lookign is to have the data in array so that i can buld my logic with array data

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what it is you want, but from my understanding if the raw data is a string and you want arrays of json marked with `END: VEVENT`. This could be a good starting place. I hope this helps you even if in the smallest way:

```js
var rawData = "BEGIN:VEVENT\r\nDTSTART;TZID=America/New_York:20161231T123000\r\nDTEND;TZID=America/New_York:20161231T133000\r\nRRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;UNTIL=20170211T045959Z;BYDAY=SA\r\nDTSTAMP:20170228T012109Z\r\nUID:h742jrf72h1r4oferera9dp070@google.com\r\nCREATED:20170102T190437Z\r\nDESCRIPTION:\r\nLAST-MODIFIED:20170211T152911Z\r\nLOCATION:\r\nSEQUENCE:0\r\nSTATUS:CONFIRMED\r\nSUMMARY:happy\r\nTRANSP:OPAQUE\r\nEND:VEVENT\r\nBEGIN:VEVENT\r\nDTSTART;TZID=America/New_York:20170106T170000\r\nDTEND;TZID=America/New_York:20170106T173000\r\nRRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;BYDAY=FR\r\nDTSTAMP:20170228T012109Z\r\nUID:ukad1og7htm89pc8j4di4otlk8_R20170106T220000@google.com\r\nCREATED:20141126T041733Z\r\nDESCRIPTION:\r\nLAST-MODIFIED:20170120T210013Z\r\nLOCATION:sds\r\nSEQUENCE:0\r\nSTATUS:CONFIRMED\r\nSUMMARY:Gold/Blue/Green Weapons\r\nTRANSP:OPAQUE\r\nBEGIN:VALARM\r\nACTION:NONE\r\nTRIGGER;VALUE=DATE-TIME:19760401T005545Z\r\nEND:VALARM\r\nEND:VEVENT\r\nBEGIN:VEVENT\r\nDTSTART;TZID=America/New_York:20161229T160000\r\nDTEND;TZID=America/New_York:20161229T164500\r\nDTSTAMP:20170228T012109Z\r\nUID:8thf9943qdnjkcrtlvt6k8kjmg@google.com\r\nRECURRENCE-ID;TZID=America/New_York:20161229T160000\r\nCREATED:20160612T220329Z\r\nDESCRIPTION:\r\nLAST-MODIFIED:20170117T200013Z\r\nLOCATION:\r\nSEQUENCE:0\r\nSTATUS:CONFIRMED\r\nSUMMARY:Juniors school\r\nTRANSP:OPAQUE\r\nBEGIN:VALARM\r\nACTION:NONE\r\nTRIGGER;VALUE=DATE-TIME:19760401T005545Z\r\nEND:VALARM\r\nEND:VEVENT\r\n"

function rawToJSON(raw) {

  var arr = [];
  var lines = raw.split('\r\n');

  lines.reduce(function(obj, line){

    var keyValue = line.split(":");
    var key = keyValue[0];
    var value = keyValue[1];

    Object.assign(obj, {[key]: value});

    if (key == 'END' && value == 'VEVENT') {
      arr.push(obj);
      return {};
    }

    return obj;

  }, {});

  return arr;

}

console.log(rawToJSON(rawData));
```

Comment: Hi....Thanks for this... I see the ouptut in expected format.... but is this in javascript? because when i try this snippet in node js... it looks like node js doesnt support...as i see error as invalid format... :(

Comment: this is what the error i got in console...SyntaxError: Block-scoped declarations (let, const, function, class) not yet supported outside strict mode
ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment
 at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
/home/vcap/app/app.js:29M
 at Module._compile (module.js:373:25)
 [key, value] = line.split(":");M
 at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)

Comment: instead let i user var as it said let is not supported function.... any idea?but your output is just what expected to build the code....but seems not supported by node js :(

Comment: @Tea hey i updated the code and removed the possible errors. I think the issue is that I wrote the code using es6 and your version of nodejs doesnt support it yet _(could be other reasons tho)_ . Let me know if this works for you now!

Comment: Awesome.. it works !! I can build my code from this...it helps...Thanks a lot!